# How to change freemarker template based on device

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am using Freemarker (v2.3.23) template with Spring MVC framework (v4).
I need to be able to apply template based upon device, i.e. template for page executed from mobile device and from desktop / laptop will be different.

One way is to detect the device type in controller, redirect to different ftl which uses different layout templates.

Or to pass the device flag to FTL and is #if directives to modify section in layout template.

I would like to know if there is any better alternate approach which also helps in leveraging ftl caching significantly.

Comment: In FreeMarker's API the `customLookupCondition` parameter of `Configuration.getTemplate()` and `Configuration.templateLookupStrategy` meant to be used for similar purposes. Spring MVC probably doesn't expose these though, at least not without some customization. But if using special template names works for you functionally, I don't think there's any problem with that.

Comment: Thanks ddekany. Concern is about performance impact in going with above strategy

Comment: Why exactly do you suspect that it can have caching problems? How many different templates do you have, and how big are they? Unless there's a lot of them and/or they are huge, I can't imagine that having, let's say, 3 times more templates can cause problems.

Comment: Yes, I will have max. 3 templates and if this will have impact on caching?

Comment: Unless you have a lot of templates (compared to the memory available), 3 times more templates hardly ever matters.

Comment: thanks @ddekany. I accept your answer